# Issue on mouse hover in button

Tags: html, button, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and I'm having some weird using when hovering over a `btn-primary` button.

This is my code :

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-small">
                  <i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Log In
                  </a>
              </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is what happens :

**before**

[image]

**on hover**

[image]

---

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: @mgraph Do you mean to totally eliminate the `btn` class??? - I'm not sure if really get your point (what I'm using is a vanilla Twitter Bootstrap... with one-or-two tweaks... that's all)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter bootstrap, buttons hover style?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501224/twitter-bootstrap-buttons-hover-style)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

2 solutions,

- Easy : Remove the a href from the li. Pro: fast, no maintenance. Con : can't do this if you need a dropdown, can break design.
- Preferrable : add missing css classes to support btn within li.

> ```
> .navbar .nav > li > a.btn {
> display: inline-block; padding: 4px 10px 4px; margin: 5px 5px 6px; line-height: 18px;
> }
>
> .navbar .nav > li > a.btn-primary,
> .navbar .nav > li > a.btn-primary:hover {
>    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
>   color: #ffffff;
> }
>
>
> .navbar .nav > li > a.btn-primary:active {
>    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
> }
>
>  .navbar .nav > li > a..btn-primary {
>   background-color: #0074cc;
>   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0055cc);
>   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0055cc);
>   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088cc), to(#0055cc));
>   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0055cc);
>   background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0055cc);
>   background-image: linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0055cc);
>   background-repeat: repeat-x;
>   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0088cc',endColorstr='#0055cc', GradientType=0);
>   border-color: #0055cc #0055cc #003580;
>   border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
>   filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
> }
> .navbar .nav > li > a.btn-primary:hover,
> .navbar .nav > li > a.btn-primary:active,
> .navbar .nav > li > a.btn-primary.disabled,
> .navbar .nav > li > a.btn-primary[disabled] {
>   background-color: #0055cc;
> }
> .navbar .nav > li > a.btn-primary:active,
> .navbar .nav > li > a.btn-primary.active {
>   background-color: #004099 \9;
> }
> ```