# Twitter bootstrap, buttons hover style?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am trying to use gradient style for my buttons, but, I have a problem with hover style,
Here is the button before hover:

[image]

And here is after hover:

[image]

Here is haml of button:

```
= link_to '#', {:class=>'tour_btn btn btn-large btn-primary', :style=>'margin-left: 10px; width: 105px;'} do
        %h3
          Take a Tour
```

LESS:

```
.tour_btn {
    #gradient > .vertical(#F98C51, #a35b35);
}
```

Any idea please ? is it possible to specify another gradient style for hover state ?
Or at least, not to change button when hover ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap animates the `background-position` on hover with a transition (since background-gradients cant have a transition). What is happening in your case, is the background-gradient is getting shifted up with `background-position: -15px`, and you are seeing the background-color underneath.

To fix this set your `background-color` to the bottom color of your button gradient on hover:

```
.tour_btn {
    #gradient > .vertical(#F98C51, #a35b35);
    &:hover { background-color: #a35b35 }
}
```

Comment: What causes this to happen though? Is it that the background color is being defined by another conflicting theme?

Answer (score 6):

If you have a set a background image for a button, the background shifts up by `15px` on hover. You can set it to `0px`.

```
.tour_btn:hover {
   background-position: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: what is this, i don't even.

Comment: This worked for me. I'm not saying that Kostia's answer is wrong, but I don't grok it.

Answer (score 5):

When using custom css instead of LESS to style your buttons, try http://twitterbootstrapbuttons.w3masters.nl/?color=%23F1874E. You will get all css for your custom buttons including hover effect and disabled / active states.

For the button above you could use possible:

```
.btn-custom-lighten.active {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
.btn-custom-lighten {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: #f29461;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f1874e, #f5a77d);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f1874e), to(#f5a77d));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f1874e, #f5a77d);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f1874e, #f5a77d);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f1874e, #f5a77d);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fff1874e', endColorstr='#fff5a77d', GradientType=0);
  border-color: #f5a77d #f5a77d #ef7736;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  *background-color: #f5a77d;
  /* Darken IE7 buttons by default so they stand out more given they won't have borders */

  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
}
.btn-custom-lighten:hover,
.btn-custom-lighten:focus,
.btn-custom-lighten:active,
.btn-custom-lighten.active,
.btn-custom-lighten.disabled,
.btn-custom-lighten[disabled] {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #f5a77d;
  *background-color: #f39766;
}
.btn-custom-lighten:active,
.btn-custom-lighten.active {
  background-color: #f1874e ;
}
```

usage:

```
<button class="btn btn-custom-lighten btn-large">Your button</button>
```

Add the CSS below /after your bootstrap(.min).css 
Using this css let's you custom button effects work in most browsers.

Comment: Just the link to the button generator tool alone is worth an upvote. Thanks for the awesome pointer!

Answer (score 4):

you can specify what you want the CSS to be when a button is hovered with the css :hover property.

So in your case you will want to do something like

```
.tour_btn:hover {
    /* your custom css */
}
```

Using chrome developer tools you should be able to see what kind of gradients are currently being applied by bootstrap and then override them with your css.

Comment: +1 for clarifying how to use :hover, how ever the ready to go answer is for Kostia :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
.tour_btn:hover {
     background-color: #a35b35;
     background-position: 30px 30px;
}
```

i found this solution you can try this . it works with simple  code