# twitter bootstrap navbar css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

My navbar custom css isn't working right
For some reason when you hover your mouse over the links it lights up the background instead of just the link.
this is what it looks like:
http://i.imgur.com/cSa26qK.jpg
this is my  css code:

```
.navbar-cloud {
  background-color: #386474;
  border-color: #284855;
}
.navbar-cloud .navbar-brand {
  color: #c1d9e1;
}
.navbar-cloud .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-cloud .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #96becd;
}
.navbar-cloud .navbar-text {
  color: #c1d9e1;
}
.navbar-cloud .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #c1d9e1;
}
.navbar-cloud .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-cloud .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #96becd;
}
.navbar-cloud .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-cloud .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-cloud .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #96becd;
  background-color: #284855;
}
.navbar-cloud .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-cloud .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-cloud .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #96becd;
  background-color: #284855;
}
.navbar-cloud .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #284855;
}
.navbar-cloud .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-cloud .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #284855;
}
.navbar-cloud .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #c1d9e1;
}
.navbar-cloud .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-cloud .navbar-form {
  border-color: #c1d9e1;
}
.navbar-cloud .navbar-link {
  color: #c1d9e1;
}
.navbar-cloud .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #96becd;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-cloud .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #c1d9e1;
  }
  .navbar-cloud .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .navbar-cloud .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #96becd;
  }
  .navbar-cloud .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a, .navbar-cloud .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, .navbar-cloud .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #96becd;
    background-color: #284855;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/4RhhF/19/)**

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a.btn-danger:hover {
    background-color: #d9534f;
    color:#fff;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a.btn-success:hover {
    background-color: #5cb85c;
        color:#fff;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a.btn-danger {
    color:#000;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a.btn-success {
        color:#000;
}
```

Consider reading this [Button hover & .btn-default styling](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/8786)

And [Twitter bootstrap, buttons hover style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501224/twitter-bootstrap-buttons-hover-style)

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the default bootstrap CSS by adding `Background: transparent;` to the following CSS rules:

```
.navbar-cloud .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-cloud .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  background: transparent;
  color: #96becd;
}
```

I have created a **JSFIDDLE** showing the result **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/4RhhF/21/)**