# bootstrap navbar button click color problems

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I had a similar to problem to this question: [Issue on mouse hover in button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374567/issue-on-mouse-hover-in-button)

And thanks to the answer from this page, it now works when I hover.

However, when I click the button, I get something similar to this:

[image: hover]

Unlike the original question, my button has a drop down menu so it may differ slightly to the original answer.

I think I just have to make a change to my CSS but I'm not entirely sure with what.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this CSS:

```
.navbar .nav > li.dropdown.open > .dropdown-toggle,
.navbar .nav > li.dropdown.active > .dropdown-toggle,
.navbar .nav > li.dropdown.open.active > .dropdown-toggle{
    color: red;
    background: blue;
}
```

And this did the job.